# How can I merge four Sales tables in Power BI without losing any data?

Tags: powerbi, append, powerquery

How do I merge four tables that have the same columns into one table? I have four tables: Sales Q1, Sales Q2, Sales Q3, and Sales Q4. Each has identical column structure. I need to merge them into one new table that holds all the sales of the Year. they all have columns Discount(Decimal number), ISBS(text), OrderID (text),ItemID(text) and Sale date(Date). I don't know how to merge them without losing the data

I have tried using different joints to merge them, but due to the same name, BI thinks there is a relation.

Answer (score 0):

This is best solved in PowerQuery (the Transform Data button). Simple select Append Queries, choose the three or more tables option, and choose the tables to combine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries#append-three-or-more-tables